# Ignore incompatible pointer types with gcc (char**→void**)

Tags: c, gcc, legacy

I am compiling some legacy C code with the purpose of migrating it to Java.
I don't want to fix the C code, I just want to run it, in order to compare numerical results.

I get this gcc 4.6.1 compilation error: `expected void** but argument is of type char**`
Written 20 years ago, this code did not care about pointer types, no big surprise.

QUESTION: How can I tell gcc to ignore these errors and compile anyway?
`-fpermissive` does not work.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: because it would take many years, no kidding.

Comment: At the very least, sprinkling explicit casts in key areas will shut the compiler up, and the code will probably continue to "work" the way it used to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of gcc are you trying to compile with? gcc 3 supported a `-traditional` flag which would tell it to behave [like a K&R C compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Incompatibilities.html), but this option isn't included in gcc 4.

You probably need to run gcc 3 somehow, like installing an OS that included it in a VM. I've read that RHEL 4 used gcc 3, you could try old FreeBSD versions, or it might be available as a package on newer OSes.

Comment: I am using GCC 4.6.1 ... I will try installing GCC 3. I unfortunately have to compile on Windows because some parts of the code include "windows.h" and "objbase.h".

Comment: Actually "-traditional -E" seems to be working on GCC 4.6.1 :-)

Comment: If the code is for Windows, why not use Visual C++ (or Borland, or whatever compiler the code was written for)? Even if you have to compile in a VM, you could probably run the exe on your normal system for the comparison work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express managed to compile the code!

Answer (score 2):

By default, gcc only emits a warning. You must be having a `-Werror` or `-pedantic-errors` flag somewhere in your compilation flags that turns this warning into an error.

```
$ cat q.c
void foo(void **x) {}
void bar(void) { foo((char **)0); }
$ gcc -Wall -c q.c
q.c: In function ‘bar’:
q.c:2:1: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
q.c:1:6: note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
$ gcc -v
[...]
gcc version 4.6.2
```

Comment: NB: This is only true for C. G++ is pickier about pointers, because that's how C++ is required to work.

Comment: Are you sure? Wrong argument types where no implicit conversion is possible are usually errors.

Comment: @duskwuff: I think you're mistaken about the C vs C++ issue. Yes `void *` converts implicitly to `char *` in C but not in C++; however, `void **` **never** converts implicitly to `char **` regardless of which language you're talking about.

Comment: "By default, gcc only emits a warning" Looks like not... I still get the error with this extra-simple compilation command line: gcc -c *.c -Iinc -lm -o out.o

Comment: @jørgensen: Thanks for the example code! It seems that this code does not compile even after removing the -Wall flag.